# using Parse.Cloud.httpRequest I am unable to set correct header for AWS request?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, header, httprequest

On Parse.com, from CloudCode I need to send httpRequest to AWS (Kinesis); they are signed and it all work when sent from the browser side (extension). I have tried the following header content-type in my request in CloudCode:

```
"content-type": "application/json"
```

> AWS refused it: {"Output":{"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException","message":null},"Version":"1.0"}

```
"content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1"
```

> parse.cloud.httprequest refused it: Result: Uncaught Error: Don't know how to convert httpRequest body Object to application/x-amz-json-1.1. To send raw bytes, please assign httpRequest body to a Buffer object containing your data.

```
"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

> AWS refused it: Request failed with response code 403

AWS documentation mentions the "application/x-amz-json-1.1" content-type everywhere and I cannot see any alternative. So, I'm assuming that's the way to go, so:

How can I ask Parse.Cloud.httpRequest to send the request with this X-AMZ-JSON header but use "application/json" ‘internally’?

update: I tried to use "http" and "xmlhttp" modules taken from Node; but none of them worked—I'm happy to try any suggestions you may have.

update: this is the actual request I'm making

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  url: awsKinesisUrl,
  headers: {
    "Authorization": concat_string,
    "action": "PutRecord",
    "acl": "public-read",
    'awsaccesskeyid': "__XXX__",
    "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
    "dategenerated":  date_generated+"",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "version": "2013-12-02",
    "X-Amz-Date": date_generated_TZ+"",
    "X-Amz-Target": "Kinesis_20131202.PutRecords"

  },
  body: {
    body: http_req_body
  },
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    var message = httpResponse.text;
    res.render('json', {message: '{response:\''+message+'\'}' });                       
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    var message = httpResponse.status;
    res.render('json', {message: '{response:\''+message+'\'}' });                       
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the blog post on sending raw bytes through httpRequest: http://blog.parse.com/2013/04/04/sending-bytes-from-cloud-code/

If `http_req_body` is a JS object, then you can use the following method call:

```
// Require can go at the global scope
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  url: awsKinesisUrl,
  headers: {
    "Authorization": concat_string,
    "action": "PutRecord",
    "acl": "public-read",
    'awsaccesskeyid': "__XXX__",
    "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
    "dategenerated":  date_generated+"",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "version": "2013-12-02",
    "X-Amz-Date": date_generated_TZ+"",
    "X-Amz-Target": "Kinesis_20131202.PutRecords"
  },
  body: new Buffer(JSON.stringify(http_req_body))
}).always(function(httpResponse) {
  var message = httpResponse.text;
  res.render('json', {message: '{response:\''+message+'\'}' });                       
});
```

I also took the liberty of replacing your success/error callback with the newer Promise technique (http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/). This not only lets you manage several API requests more easily but let you consolidate the handlers you were rewriting for both success and error conditions.